# Почему в gmail текст в теге strong фиолетовый

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, gmail, вёрстка-email

Я верстаю e-mail рассылку для gmail. И весь текст в теге strong фиолетового цвета, как у посещенной ссылке. Почему и как исправить?

Comment: `<strong style="color:#000">текст в strong</strong>`

Comment: `<strong style="color:#000 !important">текст в strong</strong>`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно к каждой ссылке или strong`у написать свой style атрибут, где будет явно задан цвет.

Ссылка: [The Ultimate Guide to emails](https://resources.emailmonks.com/infographics/ultimate-guide-email-client-hacks.html)